# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. 404 Localhost/phpmyadmin - not found

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed MaySql and phpmyadmin,
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-22-04
but for some reason they do not work on ubuntu 22:04, although everything was observed in the instructions. But localhost/phpmyadmin/ = 404 not_found
[image]

Comment: Hi! It looks like Apache2 was not configured to serve phpMyAdmin. Please carefully read the tutorial again. In "Step 1" there is a red "Warning" section. Have you pressed `SPACE` to enable Apache2 support when installing phpMyAdmin? Try uninstalling the software and following the tutorial again.

Comment: hi. I reinstalled everything but again this page, I don’t understand how to dig into Apache2. More?

Comment: I managed to get a working Ubuntu LAMP with phpMyAdmin by following the tutorial you linked (including a tutorial linked inside it, too). To reproduce the issue, I specifically tried this whole process again, but intentionally didn't press `SPACE` to select apache2 integration in the phpMyAdmin setup wizard, and indeed, that reproduced your issue. Please, make sure you DO select apache2 by pressing `SPACE` in the setup wizard before you continue — a star should appear next to it [like this](https://i.imgur.com/3ezzwTZ.png).

Comment: If this is not the problem you are having, please describe your actions and their results in detail. We do not have extrasensory perception here to guess what your problem is!

Comment: yes it turned out to install phpmyadmin if using a space to put an asterisk in the apache2 item

Everything works, thank you

Comment: Congratulations on your successful installation!